# Page Jump is jumping above content

Tags: html, css, page-jump

In in my Menu (Sticky) I have page jumps, when clicked in Chrome they jump above the content then glitch down to where it should be.
 In Safari, it just goes to above the content but then stays there

I have looked up because of the Sticky Menu but alas it brought no fix.

My code:

```
                    <ul class="ranch-menu">
                    <li><a class="active" href="#ranch-about">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#ranch-riding">Riding</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#ranch-food">Food</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#ranch-rates">Rooms & Rates</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#ranch-services">Activities & Services</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#ranch-location">Location</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#ranch-reviews">Reviews</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#ranch-contact">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>

<section class="ranch-riding ranch-section" id="ranch-riding">
more content here... blah blah blah
```

https://gyazo.com/43c1c38c7fe7273eee2ad9b42a4ae6fc

Comment: Please...no images...a [mcve] is what we need

Comment: any chance that you could post more of your code? I can't reproduce with what you have provided - thanks

Comment: @CodeBoyCode Here is my pastern of the HTML https://pastebin.com/f2sS04nG